# How to override an inherited property?

Tags: delphi, inheritance, properties, overriding

I have a class (TMyClass) which have a property (Items: TItems)

```
TItems = class;    

TMyClass = class(TComponent)
private
   FItems: TItems;
   procedure SetItems(const Value: TItems);
protected

public

protected
  property Items: TItems read FItems write SetItems;
end.

TExItems = class(TItems)
private
  FNewProb: Integer;
protected

public

published
  property NewProp: Integer read FNewProb write FNewProb;
end.

TExMyClass = class(TMyClass)
private
   FItems: TExItems;
   procedure SetItems(const Value: TItems);
protected

public

published
  property Items: TExItems read FItems write SetItems;
end.
```

The new "Items" property is inherited from TItems but when I installed the component the new property of TExItems which is "NewProb" did not appear and it looks like the "Items" property is still TItems not TExItems...how to override it?

Thanks

Modification : 
Here is the Real code

type
    TKHAdvSmoothDock = class;

```
TKHAdvSmoothDockItem = class(TAdvSmoothDockItem)
private
  FImageIndex: TImageIndex;
  procedure SetImageIndex(const Value: TImageIndex);
protected

public

published
  property ImageIndex: TImageIndex read FImageIndex write SetImageIndex default -1;
end;

TKHAdvSmoothDockItems = class(TAdvSmoothDockItems)
private
  FOwner: TKHAdvSmoothDock;
  FOnChange: TNotifyEvent;
  function GetItem(Index: Integer): TKHAdvSmoothDockItem;
  procedure SetItem(Index: Integer; const Value: TKHAdvSmoothDockItem);
protected
  function GetOwner: TPersistent; override;
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TKHAdvSmoothDock);
  function Add: TKHAdvSmoothDockItem;
  function Insert(Index: Integer): TKHAdvSmoothDockItem;
  property Items[Index: Integer]: TKHAdvSmoothDockItem read GetItem write SetItem; default;
  procedure Delete(Index: Integer);
published
  property OnChange: TNotifyEvent read FOnChange write FOnChange;
end;

TKHAdvSmoothDock = class(TAdvSmoothDock)
private
  FImageChangeLink: TChangeLink;
  FImages: TCustomImageList;
  FItems: TKHAdvSmoothDockItems;
  procedure ImageListChange(Sender: TObject);
  procedure SetImages(const Value: TCustomImageList);
  procedure SetItems(const Value: TKHAdvSmoothDockItems);
  function GetItems: TKHAdvSmoothDockItems;
  { Private declarations }
protected
  procedure UpdateImagesFromImageList;
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  destructor Destroy; override;
published
  property Images: TCustomImageList read FImages write SetImages;
  property Items: TKHAdvSmoothDockItems read GetItems write SetItems;
end;
```

Regards.

Comment: Also, in order to display something in the Delphi IDE you should start from the TPersistent class -

Comment: The new code you've included doesn't contain any classes related to each other, so what do they have to do with "overriding" anything? They also contain lots of stuff that's probably unrelated to your question. Please take care that you post a *minimal* example so as not to distract from the real issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that you don't have to be an expert at Stack Overview in order to ask good questions here. The techniques for asking good questions are universal. You'd face the same problems if you were e-mailing a friend. Your friend might be more gentle when you make a mistake, but he still couldn't answer your question with only the information you've given here so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property getters and setters can be virtual, and then overridden by inheriting classes, see below for your example updated. There's one caveat with you're example code and that's you're trying to change the type of the property, which is not allowed. I would advise you check for `Value is TExItems` in `TExMyClass.SetItems` but use the inherited Items property and cast to TExItems in all methods of `TExMyClass` and further inheritants.

```
TItems = class;

TMyClass = class(TComponent)
private
   FItems: TItems;
   procedure SetItems(const Value: TItems); virtual;
protected
  property Items: TItems read FItems write SetItems;
end;

TExItems = class(TItems)
private
  FNewProb: Integer;
protected

public

published
  property NewProp: Integer read FNewProb write FNewProb;
end;

TExMyClass = class(TMyClass)
private
   procedure SetItems(const Value: TItems); override;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for this great reply but in the TExMyClass Class the Setter procedure "SetItems" takes Value from TItems...I want it to take TExItems ? when I changed its (Value parameter) type from TItems to TExItems the compiler gave me the following error : 

[DCC Error] xxxxxx.pas(34): E2037 Declaration of 'SetItems' differs from previous declaration

how to fix this error?

Comment: Like I said, changing the property type when inheriting is not allowed. Checking the type when setting and using `Items as TExItems` should work though.

Comment: A good solution, but if the parent class is in units other than the daughter, the virtual property and the override must be in protected to work.

Answer (score 2):

Properties cannot be virtual, so they cannot be overridden. They can be *hidden*, in that within the context of `TExMyClass`, references to `Items` will resolve to the property declared in that class, not the one declared in the ancestor.

If you have something whose static (declared, compile-time) type is `TMyClass`, `Items` will always refer to the one from that class, even if its run-time type is `TExMyClass`.

You could declare `SetItems` as protected and virtual in the base class, and then override it in the descendant instead of declaring a whole new property that happens to have the same name.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement and override methods getItem and setItem;

Implement property Item only for TMyClass

```
property Items: TItems read getItems write setItemps;
```

For TMyClass:

```
public:  
function getItems : TItems; virtual;
procedure setItems(items: TItems); virtual;
```

For TExMyClass:

```
public:
function getItems : TItems; override;
procedure setItems(items: TItems); override;

function TExMyClass.getItems : TItems;
begin
  result := fItems;
end;

procedure TExMyClass.setItems(items : TItems);
begin
  self.itmes := items;
end;
```

so, TExMyClass.items.className = TExItems !

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can't override a property, but you can mimic override in several ways. See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6392378/757830) for the most basic manners.

Now I do not have the code for `TAdvSmoothDock` so the rest is just guessing. When the property getter and setter of `TAdvSmoothDock.Items` are virtual, you could override *them*. But in more advanced components, and I suppose the ones from TMS are, then there is a good chance of `TAdvSmoothDock` having a protected `CreateItem` method which is called whenever there is need of a new item which could be overriden. If that is the case, then you should implement it like:

```
function TKHAdvSmoothDock.CreateItem: TAdvSmoothDockItem;
begin
  Result := TKHAdvSmoothDockItem.Create;
end;
```

And use it like:

```
TKHAdvSmoothDockItem(AKHAdvSmoothDock.Items[I]).ImageIndex := ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the example! it is very important to read such examples before working with properties....

I was searching and I found something maybe i would help me but i need more explanation

here is my question : 
cannot I use the "reintroduce" instead of "Override"? for the setter and getter?

Comment: You could, but it is a bad idea because it would break inheritance: i.e. when the ancestor calls the setter or getter, yours wouldn't be called.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same problem as trying to have more than one TMemo that uses the same Lines object.

Since `TCustomMemo` delcares on its `private` section `FLines: TStrings;` it is not possible to have more than one TMemo that uses the same `FLines`.

The only way (i still know) of working is to fully duplicate the whole `TCustomMemo` class as `TLinkedCustomMemo`, but defining `FLines: TStrings;` on the public section; also need cloning the 'TMemo' but referencing `TLinkedCustomMemo`, not `TCustomMemo`

Then using the hack of delcaring `TMemo=class(TLinkedMemo)` you will have public access to `FLines`, so you can replace that object, with the object of the main TMemo, on all the rest linked memos.

Why do such Link on the content of the TMemos? 
Easy answer could be: Have more than one TMemo that shows the same text, so user can see (and edit) two (or more) different parts at a time, like some SpreadSheets do... it normally also involve an horizontal splitter between them, syncing horizontal scrollbars, etc.

Sometimes doing something that seems so easy, it is really so complicated!
Just caused by faulty on VCL design.

For the sample of the TMemos... why on the hell they have not been defined its Lines property based on TStringList insead of TStrings? That way we could use the same String List for more than one TMemo at the same time.

If want to see, how internally is dependant on such... search for class `TMemoStrings` (it appears on implementation section of StdCtrls). Why it must have only one TMemo?, and why it must have at all? why not had used TStringList instead of all that hell?

When some classes are so closed... it comes the hacking way of declaring classes... but how to change only a property of a control without needing to whole duplicate some classes (just to change so little things)?

Oh, yes, a real life sample for a content linked memo could be:

- Let the user see (at the same time) two different parts of a text file, without double the memory storage
- Or better sample: the user wants to edit a word on line 3 and another on line ten million without the need to scroll

So you put two TMemo and link the Lines property, so user has the controls to edit such Lines property (on different points) from both memo without need to scroll down and up all the times.

Another sample:

- User wants to edit lines one million to one million plus twenty but needs to see lines ten to twenty at the same time.
- Having to memos with a `copy` is not possible, more than 3GiB of RAM on a 32Bits Windows (not allowed), each Memo would need >1.6GiB of ram each... etc.
- Duplicating such data is neither an option, user edit on second memo, but first must be on sync... so after loose focus (or just after edit if want good looking) you would must copy all data form one to the others memos... computing time?
  -etc

There are so much samples... and most important ones are the ones i can not figure.

So answering your question in a general form, "how to hack a class to modify it a little":

1. Clone the code that define the class in a new unit, call that unit something that let clear it is for cloning that class with some modifications
2. Use the same class name only if your modifications would be backward compatile (like when additg to TEdid the Align property, use the hack of declaring it as `TTheClass=class(TheUnit.TTheClass)`), else use a different name
3. Add such new unit at the end of the `uses` of `interface` section

That is it... simple to say, hard work to do on some cases.

I allways recomend using nes classes names, except as on the sample of adding `Alignment` property to a `TEdit`.

When use the hack of declaration? When you have a full application already coded and want to add to all `TEdit` on it the alignment... insetead of creating a new component, adding it to component tools, redefine all forms to not use `:TEdit;`  and use `:TMyAlignedEdit`... you can just simple add to uses your unit and voila... all `TEdit` now have such property and IDE inspertor also sees it, etc.

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Your reply does not look like a good answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).