# Read-only Property or Function?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

For read-only properties, is there any difference between using a property with a private getter and providing a public function:

```
function GetCount : Integer;
property Count : Integer read GetCount;
```

vs.

```
function Count : Integer;
```

In terms of calling syntax these two seem to be identical. I often tend to use the second one just because it is less code, especially in interfaces where field-backed properties are not an option.

Are there any differences? (Restricted to read-only properties of course)

Comment: I think the difference is mostly in possible future extensions. You may change the getter to be function or variable, you may add setter to it, you may move property to published section, you may create some RTTI-based engine to uniformly reading properties by name or annotation, etc. Even to the point of having two properties with the same getter in base class and giving them different getters in a specialized derived one (for example using indexed properties getters). Also related q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391632/

Comment: When you are exposing a function, you are stating *here be side effect*.

Comment: @FreeConsulting I would normally agree. In this case though the code reads exactly the same `SomeType.Count` - so your point would only apply once at the time you write it.

Comment: No difference if you don't care about RTTI.

Comment: But when you refer a symbol, you can easily look up if it is a field, property or method. In the fact, productivity tools are doing that for you.

Comment: Just think about serialization. If you have to save an instance, then everything you like to save should be a (published) property, all other may be functions. Following that priciple you can serialize each instance by reading the property values with `GetPropValue`.

Answer (score 2):

1. "property is used for implementing an interface"
2. looks like in your simple case there are NO difference.

Ok, other point:

[image: Difference between method and property in assembler]

[image: When you using function]
When you using function

P.S. Interface == object - realization

Original code:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    var
            x   : integer;
  public
    { Public declarations }
        function GetX : integer;
        property MyX : integer read x;
  end;
```

......

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    s   : integer;
begin
    s := GetX;
    s := MyX;
end;
```

> Are there any differences? (Restricted to read-only properties of
>   course)

if believe to Assembler -- these construction completly identical.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please also show the original code that produced this assembler code (optimizations turned on or off?). Also, I know what an interface is, just don't see why it makes a difference for this question.

Comment: Your comparision is not valid. I am not talking about field-backed properties but about properties with a getter. Of course field-backed properties are optimized by the compiler and are much moe efficient