# Delphi: How to access variable in the Parent class from another parent class?

Tags: delphi, scope

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, IdTCPClient;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  public
    Flist : TList;
    property list : TList read Flist write Flist;
  end;

  Tmy_class = class(TThread)
    public
    procedure test;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure Tmy_class.test;
begin
  // Error here, can't access the Flist var or list propertie, help !! How to access?
  TForm1(TList).list.Clear;

  // Error
  Form1.list.Clear;

  // Error
  Form1.Flist.clear;

  // HOW ????????
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Flist := FList.Create;
end;

end.
```

How to get access to "Flist" variable ?
Thanks.

Delphi 2010, Indy 10, Win7

*Yeap, thats freeking me out:
Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.*

Comment: You need to use getters and setters. If it's java. Which it's not. I'm sure your language has an equivalent way of doing something of the sort.

Comment: None of the code you posted makes any sense. You haven't created an instance of `x`, so of course you can't access it from `y.test`. Also, you have code that won't compile - the line with `x(TList).F1.Clear` won't even pass the compiler, much less work in any way. Please edit your post and add **real**, compilable code that demonstrates the problem you're trying to solve. If not, I'm voting to close it as "not a real question".

Comment: @DMPynes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963874/usage-of-property-vs-getters-setters-in-business-classes

Comment: @waza - You already got help. Read Ken's comment. If you had an instance of 'x', you could call someX.fl.Clear.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz I edited main code, can you show example ?

Comment: @waza123, it's not clear what you're trying to do, even after your edit. `TMy_class` has no knowledge of `TForm1`, and you don't even know if there's an instance of `TForm1` created in order to be able to access it. Please try and describe what it is you're really wanting to do, instead of just posting more code that doesn't help explain. I'd really like to be able to help you, but if you can't make clear what you're trying to do, it's doubtful that I (or anyone else) can. :)

Comment: I want to have global TList, which can be accessible from all classes.

Comment: @waza - Sorry, in the earlier post the list wasn't private, so you cannot access it easily, instance or not. Unless the classes are in the same unit.

Comment: I can move list to public, just show how to access.

Comment: Code gives AV change Flist := FList.Create;
to  Flist := TList.Create;

Comment: @Orhan Cinar yes that was the problem 50% .. other 50% not solved.

Comment: @Ken - I deleted my idiotic comments. Sorry for your time..

Comment: @Sertac, not idiotic by any means. :)

Comment: You need to slow down and learn the basics before tackling threading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to address the variable Form1.

```
Form1.list.clear;
```

But doing this from a thread is not safe.

Update : compiles fine.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,     Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
 private
    { Private declarations }
    FList : TList;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    property List : TList read FList;
  end;

Type TMyClass = class(TThread)
  Public
    PROCEDURE Test;
end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FList:= TList.Create;  // Look here how to create the list
end;

{ TMyClass }

procedure TMyClass.Test;
begin
  Form1.List.Clear;
end;

end.
```

But as I warned before, using List directly from a thread is not a good idea.

See also the comment how to create your list.

And yes, the TMyClass has to be properly initiated somewhere.

Comment: I did not want to use 'var Form1: TForm1;', but think there is no choice. Why it's a not good idea to use from thread global TList ?

Comment: You should not access any VCL classes directly from threads, since they are not thread safe. There are ways to protect the list via critical sections. Or using a thread safe list.