# Use of FThumbnaiWidth vs. Get and Set in a component

Tags: delphi

Should you use:

```
property ThumbnailWidth: integer read FThumbnailWidth 
  write FThumbnailWidth default 170;
property ThumbnailHeight: integer read FThumbnailHeight 
  write FThumbnailHeight default 120;
```

or

```
property ThumbnailHeight: Integer read GetThumbnailHeight 
  write SetThumbnailHeight;
property ThumbnailWidth: Integer read GetThumbnailWidth 
  write SetThumbnailWidth;
```

Are both ways ok?

Comment: check this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963874/usage-of-property-vs-getters-setters-in-business-classes

Comment: Is the removal of the `default` clause significant to this question, or just the change from direct field access to methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends. :-)

If there are no side-effects needed, you can sometimes directly access the private variable, as in your first sample.

Often though, there are other things you need to do when the property value changes, such as update the screen, do a calculation, alter other internal values, and so forth. In that case, the `getter` and `setter` (`read` and `write` methods in Delphi) are needed.

I prefer to use the methods in the first place most of the time, as Delphi hides them from the component user. Many times they just access the internal value directly and have no other effect, but if I need to change that later there's less work to do.

Using the methods has other use as well. If you need to change *other properties*, sometimes you need to trigger (or avoid) side effects they have, and you can do that in your methods by either accessing the `published` property (such as `ThumbnailHeight` when you're changing the thumbnail width to keep proportional, and need to update the display), or accessing the internal field when you don't (by using the internal `FThumbnailHeight` directly).

See [Defining Properties](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Defining_Properties) in the documentation about the differences between [Direct Access](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Direct_Access) and [Access Methods](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Access_Methods_%28properties%29) (although the latter doesn't add much information to the first one, there are a couple of links there to read/write methods).

Comment: I personally think it's pointless having lots of getters and setters that do nothing other than read or write a field. It just leads to loads of boilerplate clutter. I always opt to refer to fields where I can. So what if you have to change it later. I prefer to pay for things as late as possible. I don't like paying for things that I never use. Handling properties is an area where C# whips Delphi's butt.

Comment: @David: It's a preference, I suppose, just like where `begin..end` pairs go, indentation, and how a `case` block is formatted. Tomato, tomahto.